# Can you run a Java jar file without going through the command line?

Tags: java

Made a game in Java and it is played using the console and the only way to run it is through the command line. Is there a way to run it without having to go through the process of going through the command line?

Comment: You can import the jar file in the IDE you are using and run it .

Comment: Yes, what kind of computer are you using?

Comment: On Windows, you can double-click a jar to execute it, assuming Java is correctly installed, and the jar has a `Main-Class` entry in its manifest (and declares its classpath in the `Class-Path` entry in the manifest0.

Answer (score 0):

Batch Files (Win), Launch4J (Win), Shell Script (Unix/Linux/OS X)

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a command line script depending on your OS which will start the game. Then you can create a shortcut and add an icon, so It will look like a common app.